# Get website metadata such as title, description from given url using Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, url, metadata

How do I retrieve website metadata such as title, description, keywords from a given url using Powershell?

for eg: given the following url

**Input:** **www.amazon.com**

**Output**

```
title: "Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more",
description: "Online shopping from the earth's biggest selection of books, magazines, music, DVDs, videos, electronics, computers, software, apparel & accessories, shoes, jewelry, tools & hardware, housewares, furniture, sporting goods, beauty & personal care, broadband & dsl, gourmet food & just about anything else.",
keyword: "Amazon, Amazon.com, Books, Online Shopping, Book Store, Magazine, Subscription, Music, CDs, DVDs, Videos, Electronics, Video Games, Computers, Cell Phones, Toys, Games, Apparel, Accessories, Shoes, Jewelry, Watches, Office Products, Sports & Outdoors, Sporting Goods, Baby Products, Health, Personal Care, Beauty, Home, Garden, Bed & Bath, Furniture, Tools, Hardware, Vacuums, Outdoor Living, Automotive Parts, Pet Supplies, Broadband, DSL"
```

**Input:** **www.youtube.com**

**Output**

```
title: YouTube
description: Enjoy the videos and music you love, upload original content and share it all with friends, family and the world on YouTube.
keywords: video, sharing, camera phone, video phone, free, upload
```

Comment: A website you are hosting in IIS?  Or another site? Questions go on from there...  Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as question.

Comment: A publicly accessible website

Comment: Can you include an example site and the expected results in the question?

Comment: @TravisEz13. I have included an example in the question.

Answer (score 5):

**Note** This only works on PowerShell 5.1 and lower.

As @StephenP said

> There is no guarantee that the website you go to will have the data
> that you want exposed in any practical way. You can easily retrieve
> webpages with Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod but then you
> will need to parse the returned headers/data

In addition, there is no guarantee that the website won't try to block what you are doing.

Below is an example of the parsing, using the .NET HTML DOM.  @tim-aitken Gave an example using RegEx to find the same information, but as he mentions this would depend on getting the RegEx right.  On the other hand, sometimes the HTML DOM cannot parse a page either.

```
# First retrieve the website
$result = Invoke-webrequest -Uri http://www.youtube.com/ -Method Get
$resultTable = @{}

# Get the title
$resultTable.title = $result.ParsedHtml.title

# Get the HTML Tag
$HtmlTag = $result.ParsedHtml.childNodes | Where-Object {$_.nodename -eq 'HTML'} 

# Get the HEAD Tag
$HeadTag = $HtmlTag.childNodes | Where-Object {$_.nodename -eq 'HEAD'}

# Get the Meta Tags
$MetaTags = $HeadTag.childNodes| Where-Object {$_.nodename -eq 'META'}

# You can view these using $metaTags | select outerhtml | fl 
# Get the value on content from the meta tag having the attribute with the name keywords
$resultTable.keywords = $metaTags  | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'keywords'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty content

# Do the same for description
$resultTable.description = $metaTags  | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'description'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty content

# Return the table we have built as an object
Write-Output New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $resultTable
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Invoke-WebRequest and then match the string that you want  using regex:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.amazon.com -UseBasicParsing

PS C:\> $response.Content -match "<title>(?<title>.*)</title>" | out-null

$matches['title']
Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more

PS C:\> $response.Content -match "<meta name=`"description`" content=`"(?<description>.*)`">" | out-null

$matches['description']
Online shopping from the earth's biggest selection of books, magazines, music, DVDs, videos, electronics, computers, software, apparel & accessories, shoes, jewelry, tools & hardware, housewares, furniture, sporting goods, beauty & personal care, broadband & dsl, gourmet food & just about anything else.

PS C:\> $response.Content -match "<meta name=`"keywords`" content=`"(?<keywords>.*)`">" | out-null

$matches['keywords']
Amazon, Amazon.com, Books, Online Shopping, Book Store, Magazine, Subscription, Music, CDs, DVDs, Videos, Electronics, Video Games, Computers, Cell Phones, Toys, Games, Apparel, Accessories, Shoes, Jewelry, Watches, Office Products, Sports & Outdoors, Sporting Goods, Baby Products, Health, Personal Care, Beauty, Home, Garden, Bed & Bath, Furniture, Tools, Hardware, Vacuums, Outdoor Living, Automotive Parts, Pet Supplies, Broadband, DSL
```

This would be dependent on all web sites using the same pattern for their meta fields. For example the above would not work for Stack Overflow's site because they close their meta field with '/>'.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the website you go to will have the data that you want exposed in any practical way. You can easily retrieve webpages with Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod but then you will need to parse the returned headers/data.